# jquery and rel attribute of link

Tags: jquery, anchor, rel

I try to add a class to a link with jquery

```
<a rel="/Career/" href="/Career/"></a>

$('a[rel=' + window.location.pathname + ']').addClass('current');
```

The above command works well with **href**, but not rel. I cannot use href and look for a good alternative. I think syntax maybe wrong.

```
$('a[rel="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').addClass('current');
```

does not work too

Comment: So $('a[href=' + window.location.pathname + ']').addClass('current'); is working , right? Do you have "rel" attributes in the link you are trying to modify?

Comment: Yes, I have added identical attributes to a link, it works with href but not rel. I cannot use href...

Comment: Try `$('a[rel="' + window.location.pathname + '"]')` instead, although I strongly suspect the real problem is that `window.location.pathname` isn't returning the string you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use it like:

```
$('a[rel="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').addClass('current');
```

only adding "

Comment: it works for me, check if window.location.pathname return what you extected

Comment: it could be a problem of slashes maybe, it could be some way escaped ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a[rel="'+window.location.pathname+'"]').addClass('current');​
```

This is working for both rel and href

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fvuqT/